# Existe alguma ferramenta online colaborativa para Diagrama de Casos de Uso e Diagrama de Sequência?

Tags: uml, diagrama, casos-de-uso

Tenho que fazer um trabalho em grupo da faculdade que consiste na confecção dos diagramas de caso de uso e de sequência. Para não ter que ficar baixando arquivo, editando e re-enviando para os outros membros do grupo, existe alguma ferramenta "tipo Google Docs" para esse tipo de diagrama?

Comment: Existe o [Gliffy](https://www.gliffy.com/uses/uml-software/) que tem recurso para colaboração além de outros listados aqui [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978983/is-there-a-google-doc-style-uml-tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978983/is-there-a-google-doc-style-uml-tool)

Comment: Você pode tentar utilizar o [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)

Comment: Para casos de uso existe uma bem fácil de usar e compartilhar chamada yuml (https://yuml.me/). Inclusive tem plugins para você usar em blogs ou incorporar em páginas HTML. Para diagrama de sequência, como depende de classes e é mais elaborado indicaria o Astah Community, mas não sei se consegue compartilhar online. (http://astah.net/editions/community)